# repeatedly apply a function to a datastructure

Tags: clojure

I would like to apply a function some number of times to a datastructure and was wondering if there is a simpler way.

```
;; simple map and map-incrementing function
(def a {:a 1})
(defn incmap [x] (update-in x [:a] inc))

;; best I could come up with
(reduce (fn [m _] (incmap m)) a (range 10))

;; was hoping for something like this
(repeatedly-apply incmap a 10)
```

Comment: You could do something like that with iterate (e.g. `(nth (iterate incmap a) 10)` but I don't understand your use case. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: my usecase is in the context of population genetics. I have a vector (population) of maps (individuals) and some functions that will modify values in individual-maps.  A function could set a flag for the individual to die/mutate (the `inc` in this question.)  A random number will determine how many of these changes should occur each round. All of my functions return the modified population vector.  I wanted to apply the `death` function N times to my population vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [iterate](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate):

> (iterate f x)
>
> Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free of side-effects

You just need to take the nth element:

```
(nth (iterate incmap a) 9)
```

Using the threading macro:

```
(-> (iterate incmap a)
    (nth 9))
```

Comment: ... so  that you can define the function you were hoping for as `(defn repeatedly-apply [f x n] (nth (iterate f x) n))`.